# How to handle multiple apis call in ios?

Tags: ios, multithreading

Suppose in my view controller i have to call 3 apis simultaneously using NSOperation Queue.

I want know that how handle multiple apis call in the same View Controller using NSoperation Queue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create an `NSOperation` for each API call and add it to `NSOperationQueue` with `setMaxConcurrentOperationCount = 3`

**A full example**:

```
    var operationQueue: NSOperationQueue = NSOperationQueue()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    operationQueue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 3;

    operationQueue.addOperation(getOperation1())
    operationQueue.addOperation(getOperation2())
    operationQueue.addOperation(getOperation3())

}

func getOperation1() -> NSOperation {
    let operation: NSOperation = NSBlockOperation { () -> Void in
        self.callAPI("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk&appid=44db6a862fba0b067b1930da0d769e98")
    }

    return operation
}

func getOperation2() -> NSOperation {
    let operation: NSOperation = NSBlockOperation { () -> Void in
        self.callAPI("http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users")
    }

    return operation
}

func getOperation3() -> NSOperation {
    let operation: NSOperation = NSBlockOperation { () -> Void in
        self.callAPI("http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts?userId=1")
    }

    return operation
}

func callAPI(urlString:String) {
    let URL:NSURL = NSURL(string: urlString)!
    let request: NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: URL)

    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request) { (data, response, error) -> Void in

        if(error != nil) {
            print(error!.localizedDescription)
        }

        do {
            let jsonData = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options:NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers )

            print("Response = \(jsonData)")

        } catch {
            print("INVALID Response")
        }

    }
    task.resume()
}
```

Comment: all the function name should be same or different one?

Comment: @akshay It can be both. I have modified the answer check it out

Comment: One more thing i want to ask.Can be add dependency on the operation  before  adding to the queue or we can add dependency  after adding the operation in the queue?

Comment: @akshay we have to add before, please refer Dependencies section in this blog, http://nshipster.com/nsoperation/

Comment: I got my answer.Thanks buddy.